# PHP session_start() error?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801178/php-headers-already-sent)

So I just joined Hostgator.com, and was wondering, why do I always get this error:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/kapip/public_html/main/mainpage.php:5) in /home/kapip/public_html/main/mainpage.php on line 7

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/kapip/public_html/main/mainpage.php:5) in /home/kapip/public_html/main/mainpage.php on line 7
```

What does this mean? I know I have to probably edit the php.ini, but I'm not sure what to change. Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Comment: yes. you are sending some output out of `<?` and `?>` before `session_start()` or possibly in the files that file `include`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any whitespace or anything else displayed before you do `session_start()` e.g.

```
// whitespace, any mark up or include that displays something <HERE>
// it will give you that error
<?php
session_start();
```

Comment: Ill accept your answer once the time wait is up. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem. The call to session_start must happen before the first HTML tag or echo statement.

Incorrect:

```
<html>
<?php session_start() ?>
```

Correct:

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<html>
```

Comment: Not just HTML tags. Any output, including whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Headers cannot be sent after output has started. Therefore, you should check `/home/kapip/public_html/main/mainpage.php` line 5 (which was indicated by the error message) for anything that results in output.