# How can i solve this errors?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801178/php-headers-already-sent)
>   [PHP session_start() error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005702/php-session-start-error)

What does this error mean?

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/html/index.php:7) in /home/content/html/index.php on line 44

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/html/index.php:7) in /home/content/html/index.php on line 44
```

Here is my code:

```
session_start ();
if ($_SESSION['username']){
echo "User: " .$_SESSION['username']."<br>";
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a> <a href='account.php'>Account</a>";
}else{
echo "<a href='index.php'>Login</a> <a href='register.php'>Register</a>";
```

I have this code on my every page when I tested it on my localhost it works fine but when I uploaded the site on my remote server it displays this error. I can't understand why I can't start a session. I am using godaddy. Please help me.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005702/php-session-start-error/6005721

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by leading whitespace. Your opening PHP tag is on line 4. It needs to be the first thing in `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If all worked on your localhost I guess you edited under Windows and published in an UNIX server, and your file encoding is UTF8 with BOM.
If right you just have to remove the BOM, with Notepad++ eg.

Comment: hey thanks for ur information yes i am useing windows but my hostion account is linux and i use dreamweaver. this is first website so i dont know much more about this can u provide me more information. in localhost all is fine but on real server some divs also not in their place.this is my code <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />