# Getting a really annoying error when I want to start a session in php

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801178/php-headers-already-sent)
>   [PHP session_start() error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005702/php-session-start-error)

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cookie - headers already sent by (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:27) in C:\xampp\htdocs\connect.php on line 2
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:27) in C:\xampp\htdocs\connect.php on line 2

I'm don't have a clue what this means or how to handle it!! ANY help will be very appreciated!

Here is my 2 files that "causes" the problem:

**connect.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'mydatabase';

if(!mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''))
{
    exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
}
if(!mysql_select_db($database))
{
    exit('Error: could not select the database');
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title> ShareLink </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="css/ui.totop.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var defaults = {
                containerID: 'moccaUItoTop', // fading element id
                containerHoverClass: 'moccaUIhover', // fading element hover class
                scrollSpeed: 1200,
                easingType: 'linear' 
            };


            $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'connect.php';
    include 'header.php';

    $sql = "SELECT
                categories.cat_id,
                categories.cat_name,
                categories.cat_description,
                COUNT(topics.topic_id) AS topics
            FROM
                categories
            LEFT JOIN
                topics
            ON
                topics.topic_id = categories.cat_id
            GROUP BY
                categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description, categories.cat_id";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo 'The categories could not be displayed, please try again later.';
    }
    else
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        {
            echo '<br/>';
            echo '<h3>Welcome to ShareLink! Here you can rate and share links with other users.</h3>';
            echo '<br/>';
            echo 'Please <a href="signup.php"><b>register</b></a> or  <a href="signin.php"><b>log in</b></a> to start sharing your links...';
            echo '<br/><br/>';
        }
        else
        {
            //prepare the table
            echo '<table border="1">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Last topic</th>
                  </tr>';   

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {               
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td class="leftpart">';
                        echo '<h3><a href="category.php?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</a></h3>' . $row['cat_description'];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td class="rightpart">';

                    //fetch last topic for each cat
                        $topicsql = "SELECT
                                        topic_id,
                                        topic_subject,
                                        topic_date,
                                        topic_cat
                                    FROM
                                        topics
                                    WHERE
                                        topic_cat = " . $row['cat_id'] . "
                                    ORDER BY
                                        topic_date
                                    DESC
                                    LIMIT
                                        1";

                        $topicsresult = mysql_query($topicsql);

                        if(!$topicsresult)
                        {
                            echo 'Last topic could not be displayed.';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(mysql_num_rows($topicsresult) == 0)
                            {
                                echo 'no topics';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                while($topicrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($topicsresult))
                                echo '<a href="topic.php?id=' . $topicrow['topic_id'] . '">' . $topicrow['topic_subject'] . '</a> at ' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($topicrow['topic_date']));
                            }
                        }
                    echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        //rate the link
                //echo '<tr><td><b>Rate this link</b></td></tr>';
    }
    //include 'footer.php';
    ?>
```

Like I said, I really need to get this working so your help will mean a lot!

Comment: Really now? Who upvotes these can't-be-bothered-to-google questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `ob_start();` above the `session_start();`. And at the end of the page, before `</body>`, put `ob_end_flush();`. I once got this error. By turning on output buffering you can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

just what the error-message and [the documentation*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) say: you have to call `session_start();` before any output is sent to the browser. in your case, include `connect.php` at the very top of your `index.php` instead of somewhere in the middle.

alternatively, just add

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

at the top of `index.php` and leave out that line in `connect.php`.

*quoting the documentation:

> **Note:**
>
> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the session before any output to the browser.

You've already output the document header etc before you include connect.php- you should initialise `session_start();` before the line `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, see the [first usage note under the SESSION reference in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to send output before setting the session. Put the `include("connect.php")` statement at the beginning of your `index.php`.

This error occurs because `session_start()` sends a cookie to the client to be able to identify the user. But cookies can only be sent to the browser if you haven't generated any output yet.

Answer (score 1):

You NEED to put the `session_start()` call before any code is sent to the client (at the start of the page).

Just put your `include 'connect.php';` right at the start of index.php !

Comment: Ok I understand but there are a couple of files that I used include 'connect.php';, not just index.php. What must I do in that case??

Answer (score 1):

there are outputs in your index page before `session_start()`.
Erase the `session_start()` from your connect.php and add it on the first line of your index page. it should work. or include your connect.php on the start of index page